# Can't find the function after require(thePackage)

Tags: r

I am trying to get the `plot.cuminc()` function in the `cmprsk` package.

I installed the package and used `require(cmprsk)` as well as `library(cmprsk)` but R still can't find the function.

p.s. I used `?plot.cuminc()` and find the help document

Dose anyone know what's wrong with the R , or my code?

Comment: What version of R are you on and what is your environment (windows, linux, os x, etc.)? Works for me on R 3.0.1 on os x.

Comment: Thanks I am using the recent undated R studio on my windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `plot` on a `cuminc` object, it will automatically run `plot.cuminc`. Try running this example code:

```
set.seed(2)
ss <- rexp(100)
gg <- factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),1:3,c('a','b','c'))
cc <- sample(0:2,100,replace=TRUE)
strt <- sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)
print(xx <- cuminc(ss,cc,gg,strt))
plot(xx,lty=1,color=1:6)
```

If you really want to look at the function, or run it directly for some reason, you can use `cmprsk:::plot.cuminc`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works know, I need to run the plot.cuminc on a data list.

Comment: @user2883693 -- If this answers your question, you can indicate that by "Accepting" it (i.e. clicking the little checkmark visible just to the left of the arrows above.

Comment: @user2883693: It is unclear what you mean by "run plot.cuminc on a data list". Edit your question to include a more complete description of the data object you want to work on.